Traverse over tree type structured data using JavaScript
I have a data set having parent and nested children in it. The purpose of this data is to traverse over parent.
     1 
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   /  \
4   5 6    7

First traverse 1,2,4 Now 4 has no children During back traverse in else part output 4, 2 then it should go to 2, 5
Now, 5 is end. Trace isVisited in parent nodes if any of the child is property isVisited as false.
5,2,1,3

Expected Output:-
1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 6, 3, 7

Once the node end is reached start traversing reverse direction from end of node to start e.g. child2 where other children were left off and were not visited yet.
Data Set in parent child relationship
[
            {
                "id": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "parentId": 0,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 6,
                                "parentId": 3,
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 11,
                                        "parentId": 6,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 10,
                                                "parentId": 11,
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "id": 8,
                                                        "parentId": 10,
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 9,
                                        "parentId": 6,
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "id": 1,
                                                "parentId": 9,
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "id": 7,
                                                        "parentId": 1,
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 4,
                                        "parentId": 6,
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]



let result = [];
const handleTree = ( tree, count) => {
        count = count || 0
        const tree = _.clone(data);
        if( tree ){
            tree.forEach( ( t: any, i: string | number ) => {
                let deepCopy = _.clone({...t });
                delete deepCopy.children;
                const { id, parentId } = deepCopy
                result.push({ id, isVisited: true, parentId });
                if( tree[i].children ){
                    handleTree(tree[i].children, count+1 )
                }else{
                    //Completed start reading backward
                    // const getPreviousParent = findParentDetails(tree[i].parentId )

                }
            })
        }
}

How to approach this problem?
So far I have been able to read the data in the same direction but, getting some unexpected results while going backward.
I tried using this code but backtrace I am not getting accurate results.
const handleTree = (tree, path = [], visited = new Set() ) => {
        let result = [];
        let count = 0;
        let visitTree = tree
        if( tree && tree.length > 0 ){
            const tree2 = (tree) => {
                if (tree) {
                    
                    tree.forEach((t, i) => {
                        count += 1;
                        let { children, id, parentId, index, ...rest } = t
                        result.push({ ...t, id, parentId, isVisited: true, sid: count });
                        tree = updateIsVisited( tree, id, parentId )
                        path?.push( t.id );
                        if (t.children) {
                            tree2(t.children.sort( ( a: any, b: any ) => b.order - a.order ) );
                        } else {
                            
                            tree = updateIsVisited( tree, id, parentId )
                            path.pop();
                            const res = returnReverseNodesForTraversel( [...path], tree, t.id );
                            // Here data is not coming correctly
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return tree2(tree)
        }
    };

Function For updating status
const updateIsVisited = ( nodesData, id ) => {

    return nodesData.map ( ( node: any ) => {
        const updatedNode = {
            ...node,
            isVisited: node.id === id ? true : node.isVisited,
            children: Array.isArray( node.children )
                        ? updateIsVisitedInNestedObjects( node.children, id )
                        : []
        }
        return updatedNode;
    })
}

I hope I have explained the question well and it is making sense. Suggestions are welcomed.

you can maybe use Depth-First Algorithm (DFS) to traverse this tree-like data structure, IIRC it uses a stack and a hashset to store with visited and unvisited nodes for each vertex. I used it once for a similar issue. Here is a Guide in JS on how to do so. Hope this helps.

It would be nice if the example you give in the beginning matched the example you give in the code. Or if you gave an expected output for the example in the code ...

Some comments on your attempt:

There is no need to clone anything when you destructure into primitives. Also the deletion of children from the clone would not be not needed.
To get the items also added on the way back, just do the same thing (the exact same result.push) as on the way down.
You don't need i. Your loop variable is the node object that you need.
There isn't a use for the count in your code. But I have added it to the generated elements. The counter better be a single number, than a separate variable for each execution, so to avoid duplicates. You can wrap that single counter in an object to achieve that.
If every output object gets a visited: true property, then it doesn't really add any useful information.

For such a traversal, a generator comes in handy: that way you don't enforce that the results are collected in an array -- you leave it to the caller to decide what to do with the values and whether or not to abort the traversal.
You could also add a property that indicates what the direction was (down or up).
Here is a possible implementation:


// Define a generator
function* handleTree(tree, counter={node: 0}) {
    for (const node of tree ?? []) {
        // No need to clone when you destructure into primitive values:
        const {id, parentId, children} = node;
        const current = { id, parentId, direction: "down", ...counter };
        counter.node++;
        yield current;
        if (children) {
            yield* handleTree(children, counter);
        }
        yield {...current, direction: "up" }; // change the direction
    }
}

// Your example tree:
const tree = [{"id": 0,"children": [{"id": 3,"parentId": 0,"children": [{"id": 6,"parentId": 3,"children": [{"id": 11,"parentId": 6,"children": [{"id": 10,"parentId": 11,"children": [{"id": 8,"parentId": 10,}]}]},{"id": 9,"parentId": 6,"children": [{"id": 1,"parentId": 9,"children": [{"id": 7,"parentId": 1,}]}]},{"id": 4,"parentId": 6,}]}]}]}];
const result = [...handleTree(tree)]; // Collect into array
console.log(result);




how can I add here the incremental ID that should be increased while going down. It should not incremented during up direction.

What should the id be for the items that represent an upward movement?

Id is not in the order. I want to keep here the track of children e.g. Node 1, Node 2, Node 3 etc...

You mean it is a child number? So if a child has itself a child, should that child get number 1 again? If not, how is the numbering supposed to come out?

No, Child 1 -> Node 1
Child of Child 1 -> Node 2
........... Child n -> Node 3

And should this be logged in the element that is returned? What about the upward elements, which number should they get then?

Right this should be logged for the Child while going down. For upward elements this should not be logged because we already append that incremental count/id while going down. It should be same for the downwards elements too.

Sorry, I don't understand. The upward elements are separate objects. What number for them?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Updated the answer according to your explanations.

I have some changes in the given structure and want to get the result as expected shared in question. Could you please check your answer. @trincot

So if I understand correctly, you no longer want nodes as output, but just an array of id values?

No, I just give an example. Like it should traverse in this way.

OK, then I don't understand. I see a function that is defined twice in a different way (handleTree) . I see a function updateIsVisited, which I don't understand why you would need this, as traversal of a tree does not need such information. I had completely forgotten about this question, so I had to reread everything again, and I see there was a lot of confusion in our exchange, and also this time I fear it will just be the same all over again. I will leave this for someone else to look into. Sorry.

I will give you the example suppose this is a graph lines and I want to navigate the user step by step over lines. If any line/node ends it should find the previous node.
Once all child completed go and search for the parent where it is unvisted and start tracking from their @trincot.

That's what my answer does. And I posted it three weeks ago. Apparently we have a communication problem here ;-)

This looks almost similar to Depth First Search (DFS) on a tree like structure.
I think for forward direction, your approach is correct. For backward direction, you need to maintain a stack of nodes. If you reach a node without children, then you need to pop it from the stack and visit other remaining children.
You can do something like this:
let result = [];
let stack = [];

const handleTree = (tree, count) => {
    count = count || 0;
    if (tree) {
        tree.forEach((t, i) => {
            let deepCopy = {...t};
            delete deepCopy.children;
            const { id, parentId } = deepCopy;
            result.push({ id, isVisited: true, parentId });
            if (t.children) {
                // push current node to stack
                stack.push({node: t, index: i+1});
                // recursively call handleTree for children
                handleTree(t.children, count+1);
            } else {
                // if no children, start backtracking
                while (stack.length > 0) {
                    let top = stack[stack.length - 1]; // peek top of stack
                    if (top.node.children && top.index < top.node.children.length) {
                        // if top node has unvisited children, visit them
                        handleTree([top.node.children[top.index]], count+1);
                        top.index++; // increment index of top node
                    } else {
                        // if no unvisited children, pop from stack
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};



Tree traversal is a classic recursive problem. Approaching this with a recursive algortihm will make the whole thing a lot easier, because you don't have to keep track of already visited nodes or keep a stack of nodes still to visit yourself.
That being said, I think, your expected output is inconsistent, ie if you reverse the order of traversal (ie children from right to left instead of left to right) it should give the reversed traveral. For this to be true, your expected outcome is missing 3 1 at the end. Ie you are adding the way back up to the root when you reach the 5 but not when you reach the 7.
Or is this because the 7 is the very last leaf of your tree? So if you have reached the very last leaf node of your tree, you don't want to add the path back to the root to the traversal?
If my first interpretation is correct, it's a simple recursive depth first traversal, with one difference, you print out the parent node before visiting the children and after traversing each child.
If you really do not need the very last route back to the root, you have to keep track on whether one of the ancestor nodes still has unvisited siblings. You only need to add a node after visiting one of its children if either (1) the node itself still has unvisited children or (2) any of its ancestors has unvisited children.
The following snippet shows both approaches.
The first function is just a recursive depth first traversal, where each node is added to the traversal before visiting any of its children. And then added again, after visiting one of its children (if there are any).
The second function is quite similar. The only difference is the additional parameter, which denotes if any of the ancestors of the currently visited node still has unvisited children. Futhermore upon visiting the children, it is determined whether the current child is the last child beeing processed or not.


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function traverse1(tree) {
  traversal.push(tree.id);
  for (let c of tree.children ?? []) {
    traverse1(c);
    traversal.push(tree.id)
  }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function traverse2(tree, addPostTraversal) {
  traversal.push(tree.id);
  for (let i = 0; i < (tree.children ?? []).length; i++) {
    let notLastChild = i !== tree.children.length - 1;
    traverse2(tree.children[i], addPostTraversal || notLastChild);
    if (addPostTraversal || notLastChild) traversal.push(tree.id);
  }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



let data = [{
    "id": 0,
    "children": [{
        "id": 3,
        "parentId": 0,
        "children": [{
            "id": 6,
            "parentId": 3,
            "children": [{
                "id": 11,
                "parentId": 6,
                "children": [{
                    "id": 10,
                    "parentId": 11,
                    "children": [{
                        "id": 8,
                        "parentId": 10,
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }, {
                "id": 9,
                "parentId": 6,
                "children": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "parentId": 9,
                    "children": [{
                        "id": 7,
                        "parentId": 1,
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }, {
                "id": 4,
                "parentId": 6,
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


let traversal = [];
traverse1(data[0]);
console.log(traversal.join(" "))

traversal = [];
traverse2(data[0]);
console.log(traversal.join(" "))




how can I keep the track here in post traversal for last item that it is my main node from where it will started again to find the next children items. The idea is I have to navigate the users through paths. These are the lines that I connected using intersection and build the tree like this. Now, I have to navigate the user from these lines by giving the indexes. First Path 0-3 S1 to B2 B2 to B3 ....... I want to track that one. e.g. [{id: 0}, {id: 3}, {id: 6}, {id: 11}, {id: 10 }, {id: 8}, { id: 10}, {id:11} {id: 6, mainParent: true }] - @derpirscher

I'm not sure if the isVisited part is needed, but assuming we don't need that and we only need to traverse the way you mention in the question, I'd say we can just do a normal preorder DFS and then also add inorder/postorder. But since you don't want to backtrack after the end, we can just keep track of the last depth visited, and then remove the last backtrack from the output array, this is the example:


const tree = [{
  "id": 0,
  "children": [{
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": 0,
    "children": [{
      "id": 6,
      "parentId": 3,
      "children": [{
          "id": 11,
          "parentId": 6,
          "children": [{
            "id": 10,
            "parentId": 11,
            "children": [{
              "id": 8,
              "parentId": 10,
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "parentId": 6,
          "children": [{
            "id": 1,
            "parentId": 9,
            "children": [{
              "id": 7,
              "parentId": 1,
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "parentId": 6,
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]

const output = []
let lastDepth = 0

function dfs(tree, depth) {
  output.push(tree.id)
  tree.children && tree.children.forEach(child => {
    dfs(child, depth + 1)
    if (!child.children || child.children.length === 0) {
      lastDepth = depth
    }

    output.push(tree.id)
  })
}

tree.forEach(child => {
  dfs(child, 1)
})

output.splice(output.length - lastDepth, lastDepth) // remove the last backtrack

console.log(output)



